# Python: "TypeError: 'Group' object is not callable"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to Python and I've just found an error I can't resolve:

```
TypeError: 'Group' object is not callable
```

Here's my redacted code:

```
    @commands.group(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def online(self, ctx):
//Some stuff

    @commands.group(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def searching(self, ctx):
        await self.online(ctx)
```

What I'm trying to do is essentially rename and make obsolete a function with an old name, and introduce it with the new name ('online' > 'searching').

Comment: Did you try implementing a `__call__` method for `group`?

Comment: @T.Woody Is that really necessary when one function just wants to call another function in the same class?

Comment: Yes, there is a distinction between callable objects and noncallable objects like `num` and `int`. You can do an `if callable(group):` to error check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`invoke`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L614) method of the `Group` object to invoke it directly from another coroutine:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.group(pass_context=True)
async def online(ctx):
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Group invoked")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def invoker(ctx):
    await online.invoke(ctx)

bot.run("Token")
```

Comment: BTW the final syntax I needed was 'await self.online.invoke(ctx)'. Thank you.